# Help needed in solving following definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I need help in solving following integral $$\int_u^{\infty}x\left(1-x^{km}(a+x^k)^{-m}\right)dx$$ where $a,m,u$ are positive real values and $k>2$. I have seen in one of the paper that the result can be written in the form of Gauss Hypergeometric function. I will be very thankful to you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

*This result has been obtained using a CAS.*

Concerning the antiderivative $$I=\int x\left(1-x^{km}(a+x^k)^{-m}\right)dx$$ $$I=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^{k m+2} \left(a+x^k\right)^{1-m}}{a (k m+2)}\,\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{k+2}{k};\frac{2}{k}+m+1;-\frac{x^k}{a}\right)$$ Concerning the limit when $x\to\infty$, I give below a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & m & k & \text{limit} \\
 1 & 1 & 3 & \frac{2 \pi }{3 \sqrt{3}} \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & \frac{10 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 1 & 3 & 3 & \frac{40 \pi }{27 \sqrt{3}} \\
 1 & 4 & 3 & \frac{440 \pi }{243 \sqrt{3}} \\
 1 & 5 & 3 &\frac{1540 \pi }{729 \sqrt{3}} \\
 2 & 1 & 3 &\frac{2\ 2^{2/3} \pi }{3 \sqrt{3}} \\
 2 & 2 & 3 &\frac{10\ 2^{2/3} \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 2 & 3 & 3 &\frac{40\ 2^{2/3} \pi }{27 \sqrt{3}} \\
 2 & 4 & 3 &\frac{440\ 2^{2/3} \pi }{243 \sqrt{3}} \\
 2 & 5 & 3 &\frac{1540\ 2^{2/3} \pi }{729 \sqrt{3}} \\
 1 & 1 & 4 & \frac{\pi }{4} \\
 1 & 2 & 4 & \frac{3 \pi }{8} \\
 1 & 3 & 4 & \frac{15 \pi }{32} \\
 1 & 4 & 4 & \frac{35 \pi }{64} \\
 1 & 5 & 4 & \frac{315 \pi }{512} \\
 2 & 1 & 4 & \frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{2}} \\
 2 & 2 & 4 & \frac{3 \pi }{4 \sqrt{2}} \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & \frac{15 \pi }{16 \sqrt{2}} \\
 2 & 4 & 4 & \frac{35 \pi }{32 \sqrt{2}} \\
 2 & 5 & 4 & \frac{315 \pi }{256 \sqrt{2}}
\end{array}
\right)$$ For $k=2$, the limit is effectively $+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually this question was a result of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954619/improper-integral-and-hypergeometric-function . I have added my attempt in that question. Can you please tell me where I am doing that question wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: @FrankMoses. I remember the previous post.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
\begin{equation}
\int x^{km+1}(a+x^{k})^{-m} \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Let $y = -\frac{x^{k}}{a}$
\begin{align}
\int x^{km+1}(a+x^{k})^{-m} \mathrm{d}x &= \frac{1}{k}a^{2/k}(-1)^{m+2/k} \int (1-y)^{-m} y^{m-1+2/k} \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{k}a^{2/k}(-1)^{m+2/k} \mathrm{B}_{y}\left(m+\frac{2}{k},1-m\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{k}a^{2/k}(-1)^{m+2/k} \frac{y^{m+2/k}}{m+2/k} {}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1}\left(m+\frac{2}{k},m;m+1+\frac{2}{k};y\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{km+2} \frac{1}{a^{m}} x^{km+2} {}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1}\left(m+\frac{2}{k},m;m+1+\frac{2}{k};-\frac{x^{k}}{a}\right)
\end{align}

Notes:
1. 
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{B}_{z}(p,q) = \int_{0}^{z} t^{p-1} (1-t)^{q-1} \mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
is the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

2.
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{B}_{z}(p,q) = \frac{z^{p}}{p} {}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1}(p,1-q;p+1;z)
\end{equation}
is the incomplete beta function in terms of [Gauss's hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Thank you for your answer for the second part in the paranthesis. I do not understand how to solve the $\int_u^{\infty}xdx$ part. Actually this question was a result of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954619/improper-integral-and-hypergeometric-function . I have added my attempt in that question. Can you please tell me where I am doing that question wrong? Thanks in advance